# vsize function not working with trim function in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, trim, procedure

Can anyone help me understand why the result of VSIZE function in my PL/SQL queries differs when I run the command on its own in the SQL plus command line and when I use it in a procedure? I understand that VSIZE displays the number of bytes in the internal representation of the expression. I've looked through many examples, and in the following example, I'm fairly sure I should get an answer lower than what I'm getting (around 12) when I run it as part of a procedure? Why isn't the answer identical in both cases, if the trim function is used on both? I need to return the number of bytes in the input (which is a full name), and so I remove trailing spaces before I invoke VSIZE. The difference in output is observed between the following two queries:

```
SELECT VSIZE( trim('   Noreen     ')) from dual;
```

and...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE HelloFullName (fullname IN NVARCHAR2)
IS
fullname_mod NVARCHAR2(50);
BEGIN
SELECT (INITCAP(TRIM(fullname)) into fullname_mod from dual;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Initial-capitalized version of name: ' || fullname_mod);
SELECT VSIZE( (trim(fullname) INTO fullname_mod from dual;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Number of bytes in name: ' || fullname_mod);
END HelloFullName;
/

BEGIN
HelloFullName('     Noreen     ');
END;
/
```

I am still new to PL/SQL, and would appreciate any insights...Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are applying `VSIZE()` to a variable of type `NVARCHAR2`.. in procedure, whereas you apply to a string directly in command prompt.

`VSIZE(NVARCHAR2)` returns two times the length of the string. And in this case it returned `2*6 = 12` (2[bytes] is size of each character) for the word you test. Where as when you do `VSIZE()` directly it gives `6`.(each char occupies 1 byte only)

From [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14195/sqlqr06.htm).

```
NVARCHAR2(size)
```

Variable-length Unicode character string having maximum length size characters.

The number of bytes can be up to ,
1) **two** times size for `AL16UTF16` encoding and 
2) **three** times size for `UTF8` encoding.

*Maximum* size is determined by the national character set definition, with an upper limit of 4000 bytes. You must specify `size` for `NVARCHAR2`.